# Unsure why I'm getting a Null exception in this loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I've got a constructor for a class that iterates over a ArrayList of `ImageIcon`s, but half way through it crashes with a NullPointerException. Any ideas why?

```
for (ImageIcon i : dm.GetIcons())
{
    _labels.add(new JLabel(i));
}

public ArrayList<ImageIcon> GetIcons(){
    return _icons;  
}
```

I tried throwing `GetIcons` into a variable and set a breakpoint, it has 8 items (exactly as I expect) but by the time I Step Over my loop 2 or 3 times it crashes. No idea what I'm doing wrong. Newbie to Java. Any thoughts?

Comment: You've added a null reference to your List. Time to do some debugging to figure out why and where.

Answer (score 2):

You have null element/s in the List of `ImageIcon`s

You can check for nullity first,

```
for (ImageIcon i : dm.GetIcons())
{
    if (i != null) {
        _labels.add(new JLabel(i));
    }
}
```

Only if it is ok to skip null elements i.e. depending on what your app needs.

Answer (score 0):

your ImageIcon ArrayList might have some null objects or a Empty object with no values